# How to get an array as a list

Tags: php, arrays, json

If I type in the wrong extention the array will show like this ["nl","net","com"] but I want it like

> nl,net,com

. How can I do that?

This is the code I use.

```
$a = array("nl", "net", "com");

$q = $_GET["q"];

$domain = explode(".", $q);

if (in_array($domain[1], $a)) {
    echo $q;
} else {
    echo json_encode ($a);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [implode()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) in `else` part:-

```
echo implode(',',$a);
```

Sample Output:- https://3v4l.org/miQ0g

Comment: @KoenM  glad to help you :):)

Comment: @KoenM  please share the question link here. I want to check that

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`implode`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

```
$s = implode(",", $a);
```